# It is OK to use a library with sensible not used code?

Tags: java, android, security, gradle

I've a Java project library (ProjectLib) that's is used in several different services/projects of a bigger solution. This library have several classes that I need to the Android App that I'm creating.

So I'm using like this in build.gradle:

```
implementation project(':ProjectLib')
```

Also in Settings.gradle:

```
include ":ProjectLib"
project(":ProjectLib").projectDir = file("../ProjectLib")
```

**This lib have some sensible and not used classes, like database access. If those classes are not used by the App it will be put in the APK? There's any risk of publishing this app and compromising any security aspects like the main database of the company?**

I mean, should I split the sensible not used classes to another lib and rework all other projects that use it? because of this security concern?

Comment: I think yes.  A library is a single part, and every part of the library just gets copied into your project and your final APK file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even unused classes will be included in the final APK file by default.

To remove unused classes from the APK you can use [ProGuard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html). ProGuard can also obfuscate your code.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the wrong question.

Meaning: your APK should **never** ever expose security relevant information to the world! It doesn't matter whether your APP is actually relying on some specific classes or not.

The other answers are correct in the sense of: you can fine-tune the exact content that goes into an APK using this or that technology. But as said, the **real** answer is to **never** have content in APK that gives away **secrets**.

( and just for the record: a server name or IP address is *not* a secret )

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely that sensibly developed and unused java library classes in an android application contains such exploitable elements that it is a security threat.

Unless these classes are a security threat in general.

Keep in mind that the "other" application can also include classes and libraries.

Also keep in mind that most of the times applications use only a small portion of the included library jars. 
If it is OK to use only a tiny portion of guava then it is OK to use a tiny portion of your library too.

That being said you also would like to have your .apk reasonably sized. An obuscator such as ProGuard could help reduce the size of your application as well remove unused code. ProGuard can  remove not only unused classes but also unused methods inside used classes.

In any case to define how secure is a solution you need to define the threats against which the solution is secured. 
(Threat analysis)